# sass compile error - StalenessChecker::Mutex (NameError)

Tags: ruby, compilation, sass

Any ideas on this error - the sass compilejust fails - have tried gem update --system and gem update and remove and reinstall sass gem

```
sudo sass --update --trace styles.scss overwrite styles.css
Password:
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.11/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/plugin/staleness_checker.rb:27: uninitialized constant Sass::Plugin::StalenessChecker::Mutex (NameError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.11/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/plugin/compiler.rb:7
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.11/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/plugin.rb:4
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.11/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/exec.rb:381:in `watch_or_update'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.11/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/exec.rb:326:in `process_result'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.11/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/exec.rb:41:in `parse'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.11/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/exec.rb:21:in `parse!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.11/bin/sass:9
    from /usr/bin/sass:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/sass:23
```

Comment: Same error, appers today, with ruby 1.8 sass 3.2.11 compass 0.12.2 and buildout

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This same issue started popping up for me today.  I suppose there is something wrong with sass-3.2.11 or some configuration that I am not aware of.

To get past the issue for now I uninstalled the new version and installed an older version like so:

**Uninstall sass**

```
gem uninstall sass
```

**Install version 3.2.10**

```
gem install sass --version 3.2.10
```

**Reinstall compass**

```
gem install compass
```

Comment: There's a small error in the command to install sass; it should read like this: gem install sass --version 3.2.10

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in sass 3.2.12.

[Sass Issue Queue](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/941)

So all you need to do is update your sass gem

```
gem install sass
```

Should pull the latest version 3.2.12 or greater

Answer (score 0):

i previously had updated the default OSX version with:

```
gem update --system
```

This created the problem - not a good idea to do on the 'out of the box' OSX version.